# AngularJs Bi-Directional sort filter Example?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

**How to implement bidirectional sort filter example?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angularjs-Bidirectional Sort </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<style type="text/css"> 
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Arial;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
th{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
.arrow-up{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid black;
display: inline-block;
}
.arrow-down{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-top: 10px solid black;
display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<body >
<p> 1.How to implement bidirectional sort in Angular<br>
    Use orderByfilter <br>

</p>
<div ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">

    <table border="1">
        <thead><tr><th ng-click="sortData('name')">Name <div ng-class="getSortClass('name')"></div></th>
        <th ng-click="sortData('dateOfBirth')">Date of Birth<div ng-class="getSortClass('dateOfBirth')"></div></th>
        <th ng-click="sortData('gender')">Gender<div ng-class="getSortClass('gender')"></div></th>
        <th ng-click="sortData('salary')">Salary(Number) <div ng-class="getSortClass('salary')"></div></th>
        <th ng-click="sortData('salary')">Salary(Currency)<div ng-class="getSortClass('salary')"></div></th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | orderBy:sortColumn:reverseSort">
                <td>{{employee.name | uppercase}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.dateOfBirth | date:dd/mm/yyyy}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.gender | lowercase}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.salary | number:2}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.salary | currency:"Rs: ":1}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

//creating the module ,controller and registering with the module all done in one line
//Use the method chaining mechnism as show below:
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []).controller("myController",function($scope){
    var employees = [
            {name:"Pramod",dateOfBirth: new Date("February 01,1987"),gender:"Male",salary:45799.50},
            {name:"Dipika",dateOfBirth: new Date("May 29,1987"),gender:"Female",salary:50799.50},
            {name:"Vasant",dateOfBirth: new Date("May 22,1990"),gender:"Male",salary:40000.50},
            {name:"Navanath",dateOfBirth: new Date("June 12,1987"),gender:"Male",salary:51799.50},
            {name:"Komal",dateOfBirth: new Date("March 29,1991"),gender:"Female",salary:54799.50}
    ];
    $scope.employees = employees;
    $scope.sortColumn = "name";
    $scope.reverseSort = false;

    $scope.sortData = function(column){
        $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn==column)? !$scope.reverseSort:false;
        $scope.sortColumn = column;
    }
    $scope.getSortClass = function(column){
        if($scope.sortColumn == column){
            return $scope.reverseSort? 'arrow-down':'arrow-up';
        }
        return '';
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question, or is this part of your question? (if it's the latter, you should delete this answer and move your code to the question).

Comment: actually, I am new for angularjs and i had faced problem for bidirectional search . I have resolved this like this so , i felt to share here to help out some one.

Comment: Thanks. Very precise ans for new candidate to AngularJS

Comment: A great and detailed solution. +1 to you... :)

Answer (score 2):

I have already build a solution for this case, but the repository isn't available for the moment.

Example for text (or date)

```
var vm = this; //head of your controller
vm.sortBy = {type:'ouvertes',name:'ouvertes'};
vm.sortFunction  = sortFunction;

    /**
     * @param  {Object}
     */
    function sortFunction (sortBy){
         var reverse = false;
         if(sortBy.order == "desc"){
            reverse = true;
         }

         vm. xx(name of your list) = $filter('orderBy')(vm.xx(name of your list), sortBy.type, reverse);
    } 

  /*
   * sort is object and type is the column youy want to sort (that suppose you have list of objects )
  */
```

To trigger the sort set ng-click on the thead of your table and params they will be passed to function ex (ng-click="youctrl.sortFunction({order: '1', type: "nameofyourobjectproperty"})"

and trigger a click manually to set the default sort.

Comment: Ans is quite complex

Comment: If you find this so complex, and you haven't other solution i can create an example, is very simple.